# Multiple Django versions - is virtualenv still a good choice?

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv

I'm doing python/django work on Mac OSX. Python 2.7 for my current projs.

I've managed to avoid needing virtualenv for a couple of yrs, although it always looks like a good solution when faced with managing concurrent versions.  I'm eager to move to the latest Django version (1.7) but don't want to break another project I have under 1.5. (It's not public, so I'm not worried about security issues pre-1.7 just now).

Is virtualenv still a good way to enable two concurrent environments, or is there something more useful that kids today are using.  Just don't want to go down the virtualenv path if there's a better direction to pursue/learn.

Comment: Why would you avoid `virtualenv` it's such a useful tool! (I mean that said you can always use a shell script to change your python-path or `sys` - but why would you?)

Comment: Virtualenv is also a good way to not mix dependencies between multiple projects, and to guarantee that you've tested against the mimimal set of dependencies – iow that you have your dependencies listed correctly. It's entirely appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: Virtualenv is fine, but I get your point: when you're deploying with Docker containers, it's not needed.

Comment: @StanislavShabalin, VMs are another good way to isolate your environment but I still say its worth it to use virtualenv.  What happens when you have multiple python applications on the same VM?

Comment: @garnertb VMs - you're right. My point was about container virtualization which is more... cool and relevant today, to the question's point ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't look at a virtual environment as an obstacle, instead it should be the cornerstone of your Python development experience.  Virtual environments allow you to isolate your python packages from the system's packages in a local location and destroy it and recreate it to your hearts content.  The problem with not using a virtual environment is that you don't realize you've screwed up your global python packages until its too late and recovery is painful.  Since all it takes is a one-liner to create a virtualenv and prevent a very painful experience, I don't see any reason not to use one even if you don't think your project needs one.  So in short, the answer is 'yes' virtualenv is the tool to use but also check out [virtualenvwrapper](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvwrapper) for a friendlier interface.

Comment: Great - sounds like it's still in favour, so I will embrace the virtual.    Thx for the pointer to virtualenvwrapper too.  :)